# Excel VBA - Remember SQL ODBC User/Password

Tags: sql, vba, excel, odbc

First time here, so I hope to get my answer, I looked throughout the Google but I couldn't find the answer.

Well, I got VBA code which refresh a code in SQL on Exel.

VBA code: `Selection.ListObject.QueryTable.Refresh BackgroundQuery:=False`

It's asking everytime my ODBC login/password and I try to refresh manually, and I'd like to run automatically by saving those information on Excel Cells or in VBA directly (I prefer a variable that is linked in excel cells in "Validação de Dados" sheets). And after that, making it better by forcing the user to insert those information in a form (to keep better looking).
But the problem is that everytime I tried to run the macro, it gets an error (something like **"authenticantion failure"**).

- **My SQL code in Excel location:**

[image: SQL Code Window]

- **Asking about my user and login:**

[image: User/Login]

- **Error getting by not saving user/login:**

[image: Error Trying to Use VBA Code]

Office version: Microsoft Office 365 Business

Thanks everyone!

Comment: you can choose to store the u/p directly in the data connection file where it says "cadeia de conexao". Add `UID="user";PWD="pwd"`

Comment: That could work only with one (or mine) information right ? Because this query will be available for a lot of people, so everyone has their own "user" and "pwd".

So I'll create a form and link those information in a "text box" in Excel cells or something else that could work fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to ask the password from the standard window with this code:

```
ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Base").ListObjects(1).QueryTable.Refresh
```

"Base" is the name of your worksheet, and `ListObjects(1)` is if you have only one SQL query.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to use windows integrated authentication as well if you have an SQL Server.  You'd have to add your user in SSMS.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/connect/odbc/linux-mac/using-integrated-authentication?view=sql-server-2017

Comment: Sorry, I didn't find the correct answer, also I don't want trusted connection, they'll need to insert their own "user" and "pwd", as I said above.